# Inserting row using Google Sheets API

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am trying to understand Google Sheets API. Here is the spread sheet that I am using.

[image]

I am trying to add a worksheet to this sheet by following Googles tutorial. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#add_a_worksheet

public class GoogleSheetsApiTest {

```
public static void main(String[] a)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, ServiceException, URISyntaxException {
    new GoogleSheetsApiTest().testConnectToSpreadSheet();

}

private final String CLIENT_ID = "snip";
private final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
private final static String P12FILE = "snip.p12";
private final static String WORKSHEET_ID = "snip";

public void testConnectToSpreadSheet()
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, ServiceException, URISyntaxException {

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("sheetsbot");
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    GoogleCredential credential = getCredentials();
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + WORKSHEET_ID + "/private/full");

    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

    WorksheetEntry worksheet = new WorksheetEntry();
    worksheet.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("New Worksheet"));
    worksheet.setColCount(10);
    worksheet.setRowCount(20);

    URL worksheetFeedUrl = spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl();
    service.insert(worksheetFeedUrl, worksheet);
}

private GoogleCredential getCredentials() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    URL fileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(P12FILE);

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setServiceAccountId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(fileUrl.toURI())).setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .build();

    return credential;
}
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Sheet1
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad      Request
Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead.
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
at GoogleSheetsApiTest.testConnectToSpreadSheet(GoogleSheetsApiTest.java:69)
at GoogleSheetsApiTest.main(GoogleSheetsApiTest.java:27)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong or how I could try this differently.

Comment: I believe you need to define the column names. Refer to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_list_row) for adding rows. Notice that it defines the header row: `row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal(name, value);`

Answer (score 0):

I have code for adding sheets that is working. I use:

```
key = the spreadsheet key

service.insert(new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + key
                + "/private/full") , worksheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding any rows to your worksheet?

```
    // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
    // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
    // app's needs.
    WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
        spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

    // Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
    URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
    ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

    // Create a local representation of the new row.
    ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("firstname", "Joe");
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("lastname", "Smith");
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("age", "26");
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("height", "176");

    // Send the new row to the API for insertion.
    row = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);
```